# Stepping down/up center tapped transformer

Tags: transformer, audio, buck

I've got a Hifi setup to repair where the power amplifier died. I want to replace it with a different one. There is a center tapped transformer that provided +-35 volts DC for the original amplifier. My question is: can I use two buck converters to step the voltage down/up to +-20 volts?

One for the positive rail - V+ on converter to V+ on transformer and GND on converter to GND on transformer. The second one for negative rail - V+ on converter to GND on tranformer and GND on converter to V- on transformer.

Or will I blow something up?

The old amplifier was 50W and the new one is 20W (which is plenty) so I would not wory much about overloading the converters.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: Most likely the bulk ecaps all need to be inspected and-or all replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Your transformer won't be supplying DC voltages, it will supply an AC voltage to another circuit board with a bridge rectifier (square black thing) and two electrolytic capacitors (round blue things), this PCB will have voltages of +35VDC and -35VDC.

While you could connect a buck convertor to reduce the +35VDC to +20VDC, you can't use the same type of convertor for the negative supply, as the buck converter has both negative terminals connected together. You might be able to find a negative supply buck converter, but they would be rare. You could however use an isolated convertor for the negative supply.

If your transformer had two seperate windings, then you could use two rectifier bridges, two capacitors, and two buck converters.

Sometimes just getting another transformer is simpler!

Note. In case you are not aware of it, the rectified DC voltage is 1.4 times the AC voltage of the transformer, so a 20VAC winding produces 28VDC,  a 24VDC winding produces 34VDC, a 14V winding produces 20VDC.

Comment: I am aware of transformer supplying AC voltage and the rectified voltage being 1,4 times higher (or square root of two times to be exact, or at least in theory). I just left it out to make the question shorter. Another transformer is not an option because the transformer has many output voltages (5-6 I think) and +-35 volt are just two of them. I have also been thinking about splitting the positive rail in half using virtual ground.

Comment: OK , a simple supply splitter using a NPN/PNP emitter follower pair might work, They would just follow the centre tap of a resistive divider. you would need larger filter capacitors than normal maybe double,  The rail splitter should not be drawing a huge current as it's only balancing the capacitors. and the +/- 0.6v Vbe will allow some "rattle space" . Just be careful to seperate the mid point of the +/-35 supply from the amplifiers earth,